# IntelliJ live template. Remove or replace number at the beginning of filename

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

I have database migration files with timestamp at the beginning of the filename. For example:
`1537865596694-create-config-table.migration.ts`

There is expression you can use to convert filename to Typescript class name:
`capitalize(camelCase(fileNameWithoutExtension()))`

But I can't find an option to remove or replace number.

Comment: You can use GroovyScript inside Live templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `groovyScript("groovy code")` (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions, http://bartololeo.blogspot.ru/2014/01/idea-12-how-to-write-live-template-with.html. Like:

```
groovyScript("def res=''; def fname=_editor.getVirtualFile().getNameWithoutExtension(); def index=fname.indexOf('-'); if
(index!=-1) res=fname.substring(index+1, fname.indexOf('.')).replaceAll('(-)([A-Za-z0-9])', { Object[] it -> it[2].toUpperCase() } ) else res=fname; return res")
```